# Creating text file from two differerent folders in python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a list with two different file folders (to a text file) in python; however, when I run my program only my second file path appends to the list and appears in my text file. How can I append my list so that the files in both folders display? I think my code is emptying the list after the first step. I want to keep the two folders separate and don't want to combine them just for the sake of the list.

```
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

root = r'C:\GEO\Images\data\data_2008\ims_data_2008'
mylist = [ ]
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
     for name in files:
          mylist.append(os.path.join(path, name))

roottwo = r'C:\GEO\Images\data\data_2009\ims_data_2009'
mylist = [ ]
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(roottwo):
     for name in files:
          mylist.append(os.path.join(path, name))

txt = open(r'C:\GEO6973\FinalExam\YoungResults\ims_data_list.txt', 'w')
txt.write('dir' + ',' + 'file' + '\n')
for item in mylist:
     list = mylist.pop(0)
     dir, filename = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(list)), os.path.basename(list)
     txt.write(dir + ',' + filename + '\n')

with open(r'C:\GEO6973\FinalExam\YoungResults\ims_data_list.txt', 'r') as f:
     read_data = f.read()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, your code is emptying the list after the first folder. You'll have to remove the second `mylist = [ ]` after `roottwo`, otherwise you will lose all data appended to the list thus far.

In the final loop, if you are trying to iterate over the paths appended to `mylist` don't use `pop` to access its contents. Instead:

```
for item in mylist:
    dir, filename = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(item)), os.path.basename(item)
    txt.write(dir + ',' + filename + '\n')
```

Finally, try to avoid using `list` as a variable name since it is a reserved keyword in python.

Comment: If I remove themylist after  roottwo, only the root file writes to my list.

Comment: That should not happen after you remove the re-definition of `mylist`. After the first declaration, you only append items. If you print `mylist` before opening the output file you should have the contents of both folders.

Comment: Removing the re-definition doesn't help. I think it has something to do with my mylist.pop(0) statement.

Comment: Well, the original problem of having only files from the second path is caused by the second `mylist=[]`. In the final loop, try to remove the `list = mylist.pop(0)` and replace `list` with `item` in the contents of the loop. Also, avoid declaring variables using `list`, since this is a reserved keyword.

Comment: That worked. I took out the pop statement but hadn't updated the basename dirname etc.

Answer (score 1):

After `rootwo` is set you are then calling `mylist = [ ]`.  This creates a new list, effectively erasing all data that you previously appended to the list.